# 3 monitors in 1 graphic card. Need that 2 monitors shows the same except 3rd monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I want to put 3 monitors in same grapic card (DVI,HDMI and VGA). 
But I have the problem that I need to put a program in fullscreen on monitor 01, a excel in fullscreen on monitor 02, and in the third monitor need to show the same as in monitor 01.

There is any way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

On windows you can right click on the desktop. Select screen resolution duplicate monitor 1 to monitor 2, extend to monitor 3.

[image: Desktop - screen resolution]

Then select "extend" for different screens and mirror for identical content.
[image]

If your question was for another OS then please specify that OS in the post.

Note that a graphics card with three outputs does not guarantee that the card supports this. Also note that this should work with with multiple add-in cards.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply configure a dual-monitor setup and use a [splitter cable](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/152030/Tripp-Lite-DVI-Dual-Link-Splitter/) connected to monitors 1 and 3. This would be the simplest solution in my opinion, the only catch is that monitors 1 and 3 would need to have the exact same specifications.